# Can I use the non-first move in a Linked Move sequence?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon

So when you set up Linked Moves, when you select the first Move in the sequence, all the other moves fire off in order. Say I set up a sequence like:

1. Leer
2. Tail Whip
3. Quick Attack

Can I select Quick Attack and use it by itself?

Answer (score 1):

To use Quick Attack separately, you need to unlink it. ( I don't remember how to do it, but i am sure that it cab either be done by yourself or from the shop)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a dungeon where you can change which of your party members is the leader, it's as simple as changing the leader to the pokémon with quick attack and then using it, without doing any of the linked move stuff.

If you want to change the order of moves in a linked move sequence, you can do this through the menu by changing the party order.

But in dungeons where you are forced to only use one pokémon as the leader, there is no way to force a party member to use a certain move outside of links, which make you use all three moves.